# Used Web Platform installer to install the MVC Framework but the MVC template isn't available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation

I just installed Visual Web Developer and the MVC Framework using the Web Platform installer, I used the ASP.NET option and it says that MVC is installed, but it doen's show up in the templates list when I open a new project.

I installed in Windows XP with a limited user (typed the Administrator password to allow the install) I guess this is the problem, but, how can I fix it?

I tries logging in with the Administrator account and executing the MVC installer but still can't get the Template in Visual Web Developer.

Any clues? Or any way to register the templates manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uninstalled the MVC Framework and installed it again, now the templates are registered just fine.

Don't know what I did wrong the first time, but luckily it's working now.