# How to install ASP.NET MVC 2 templates after already installing VS Web Dev 2010 first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

First off these questions are related but do not fix my problem:

> [Missing Project Template after installing ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499934/)
>
> [Used Web Platform installer to install the MVC Framework but the MVC template isn't available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652836/)

I have installed Visual Studio Web Developer Express Edition 2010, then I installed MVC 2. Now I can successfully run a MVC 2 application, however I have to do the manual imports of the namespaces and stuff.

How can I install the templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try copying the project templates from the default folder into the personal templates folder. To do this:

1. Go to "*%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033*" (folder might vary since I'm using VS2010 Ultimate, but you can locate the folder easily by just looking for **ProjectTemplates** folder at %PROGRAMFILES%).
2. Locate and copy the **MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev2.0.cs.zip** and **EmptyMvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev2.0.cs.zip** files into "*%HOMEPATH%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#*"
3. If you are running Visual Studio you'll need to restart it before you can see any effects.

Note that if you are VB.NET instead of C# you'll need to adjust the provided paths to match VB.

Nevertheless I'd suggest that you try uninstalling and then re-installing ASP.NET MVC since this steps won't plug-in all the tooling MVC provides for VS.

Comment: One problem with your solution. They aren't installed there (or at all). I was hoping someone could just tell me where to download them. However Uninstalling / reinstalling worked.